# Getting Facebook Share, Like and Comment Counts for a Given URL with API Graph v2.6

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

[As both Legacy REST API and Facebook Query Language (FQL) will no longer be available after 7th August](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) I am looking for an API Graph v2.6 based on alternative to:

- https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/&format=json
- [https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count,commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/'](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20normalized_url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,commentsbox_count,%20comments_fbid,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%27http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/%27)

So far, this is my v2.6 current equivalent: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?id=YOUR_URL&fields=og_object{engagement},share{share_count}&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN` Nevertheless `og_object{engagement}` `count` and `share_count` seem to maintain some total count instead of like and share counts, respectively (see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/url).

Please does anybody know how to get Facebook share, like and comment counts for a given URL with API Graph v2.6? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I reported a bug on [https://developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/) Here is the response:

- In relation to Legacy REST API and Facebook Query Language (FQL) officially they will stop working after 7th August 2016.
- Secondly, about `count` and `share_count`, any engagement on a shared link on Facebook (including likes and comments) is considered as additional shares, as the people who like and comment on the shared link also generate a story for their action on their own timelines. To illustrate this further, I paste a quote from current Facebook Engineer:

> (...) if person A shares a link (for example, http://fb.me/), this generates a story on person A's timeline. If person B comments on this story, this in turn generates a story on person B's timeline. Querying `/?id=` via the Graph API would then return a `share_count` of 2.

I hope it helps.

Comment: So there is no way to get like count without an access token?

Comment: If Legacy REST API and FQL are now officially deprecated, no. But it just takes a few minutes to create a new app in order to use its access token

Comment: I see, thats what I've done. I've created and app and used the Graph API with a newly created access token.

Comment: So there is *no way* to get shares, likes, comments as before? This is so frustrating, the FQL returned exactly what we needed before.  So, *somewhere* the likes & comments are being tracked separately from shares.  Surely there must be some way to get this info still?

Comment: It seems to me that Facebook is working in something more urgent now and they have had no time to implement this in the API Graph yet